# Why doesn't the component tag in Vue3 work properly for dynamically rendering components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I'm just learning Vue and trying to learn dynamic rendering using the component tag. What is the problem with this code? No errors are displayed in the console, but clicking on the buttons still does not display the required component. It does work with v-if, but the point of this lecture I'm following is to use the component dynamic rendering. Which does not work:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <the-header></the-header>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('active-goals')">Active goals</button>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('manage-goals')">Manage goals</button>
    <component :is="selectedTab"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { ref, defineExpose, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';
import ActiveGoals from './components/ActiveGoals.vue';
import ManageGoals from './components/ManageGoals.vue';

const selectedTab = ref('active-goals');
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};

defineExpose({
  selectedTab,
  setSelectedComponent,
});

defineComponent({
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    ActiveGoals,
    ManageGoals,
  },
});
</script>

<style>
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
</style>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Move the component imports and their registration into a separate `<script>` tag, as shown in my answer. Details [here](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script). If the components are not registered, you can't use strings in `:is` to reference them. The alternative is to use the component themselves instead of strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use strings with `:is` if the components are not registered.

You either use the components themselves instead of the strings (@Tolbxela's or @Bussadjra's answers), or register the components.
And you can't register the components (easily) in `<script setup>`, because `<script setup>` syntax is limited. It's literally a macro to write:

```html
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    // CODE HERE
  }
})
```

as:

```html
<script setup>
// CODE HERE
</script>
```

... with some mods to allow `import`s inside the `setup()` function and few more other goodies (`defineProps`, `defineEmits`, etc...).

The limitation should be obvious: if you need anything besides the contents of `setup()` function from `defineComponent()`, you want to use a normal `<script>`.

In other words, `<script setup>` should be treated as a tool to reduce boilerplate, you shouldn't put effort into attempting to write all your components using it.

Last, but not least, `<script setup>` can be used [alongside a normal `<script>`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) tag. In your case:

```html
<script setup>
const selectedTab = ref('active-goals');
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};
</script>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';
import ActiveGoals from './components/ActiveGoals.vue';
import ManageGoals from './components/ManageGoals.vue';
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    TheHeader,
    ActiveGoals,
    ManageGoals,
  },
});
</script>
```

The normal `<script>` registers the components so `<template>` can translate the strings into actual components.

Comment: Perfectly clarified! I have updated the playground and it works!

Comment: Thanks for the perfect explanation! However, when I try to use your code (which does work in the playground), my app crashes, with a lot of errors. Any idea why it could be?

Comment: @mrcrazyog, not without knowing what *"a lot of errors"* actually means. What are the errors? Can you create a *runnable* [mcve]? Make sure there are no syntax errors (unclosed brackets or tags, etc...) and also try restarting the dev server. That helps sometimes.

Comment: @tao no worries, I figured it out. The problem was caused by how the project was packaged I think. I originally downloaded the files from my instructor, ran npm install on the repo and worked with it. But I think it might have been created in a "deprecated" way (probably using Vue CLI?) that somehow did not allow two script tags. (is that possible? or possibly, the issue was with a wrongly configured ES-lint?). Not sure. But now I've re-built the project with Vite and everything works perfectly! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In script setup the imported components are treated as variables because they're not registered under keys as we do in `components` option in non script setup syntax, so you can map them with keys inside an object :

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <the-header></the-header>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('ActiveGoals')">Active goals</button>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('ManageGoals')">Manage goals</button>
    <component :is="selectedTab"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { ref, defineExpose, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';
import ActiveGoals from './components/ActiveGoals.vue';
import ManageGoals from './components/ManageGoals.vue';

const selectedTab = ref(ActiveGoals);
 const components = {
    ActiveGoals,
    ManageGoals,
  }
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = components[tab];
};

defineExpose({
  selectedTab,
  setSelectedComponent,
});



</script>
```

Comment: Accessing the components directly is also a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**

[Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with the tao's solution

---

**UPDATE**

Answering the question from tao:

To make `<component :is="">` work with strings, you have to register you components with names.

---

You don't need `defineComponent` in this case.

Check the original [Vue Solution for Tabs](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) in the [`Dynamic Components`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components)

Working [Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) with your code

Here is you fixed code:

```
<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { ref, defineExpose, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from './TheHeader.vue';
import ActiveGoals from './ActiveGoals.vue';
import ManageGoals from './ManageGoals.vue';

const selectedTab = ref('active-goals');
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};

const tabs = {
  'active-goals': ActiveGoals,
  'manage-goals': ManageGoals
}

</script>

<template>
    <the-header></the-header>
    selectedTab: {{selectedTab}}<br/>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('active-goals')">Active goals</button>&nbsp;
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('manage-goals')">Manage goals</button>&nbsp;
    <hr/>
    <component :is="tabs[selectedTab]"></component>
</template>
```

Comment: According to [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) `:is` should work with strings out of the box (*"`:is` can contain [...] the name string of a registered component"*). You shouldn't have to pass actual components. And your answer doesn't answer the question, which basically is: *"why doesn't it work with strings, as it should?"*. Your answer provides a workaround, in which the keys of `tabs` could be `'foo', 'bar'` - they're irrelevant. The relevant part is that you're passing the component themselves to `:is`. Why is this necessary?

Comment: I also asked this on [Vue's discord](https://discord.com/channels/325477692906536972/568037134968160256/1089906588992684093). The gist of the answer is that imported `.vue` files are not components. They're just variables. So they're not registered. When the `<template>` finds an unknown component, it checks the local context for any variable with that name. If it's there and it's a `.vue` import, it's used. In order to use strings with `:is`, a component has to be registered.

Comment: I was considering removing my answer, since you included the code it in yours, but I'll leave it as it explains in more detail exactly why it works.

Comment: @tao I think your answer should be accepted. Thank you very much for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

for this to work you can register your components globally, for Vue to make the link with your selected component. Otherwise, you can use the defineAsync method from Vue.

[registerGlobally](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#global-registration)

[defineAsync](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html#basic-usage)

1:
your .vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <the-header></the-header>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent(ActiveGoals)">Active goals</button>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent(ManageGoals)">Manage goals</button>
    <component :is="selectedTab"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { ref, defineExpose, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';

const selectedTab = ref('active-goals');
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};

defineExpose({
  selectedTab,
  setSelectedComponent,
});

defineComponent({
  components: {
    TheHeader,
  },
});
</script>
```

In your main

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import ActiveGoals from './components/ActiveGoals.vue';
import ManageGoals from './components/ManageGoals.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
app.component('active-goals', ActiveGoals)
app.component('manage-goals', ManageGoals)
app.mount('#app');
```

2:
your .vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <the-header></the-header>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('active-goals')">Active goals</button>
    <button @click="setSelectedComponent('manage-goals')">Manage goals</button>
    <component :is="selectedTab"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { ref, defineExpose, defineComponent } from 'vue';
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue';
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const ActiveGoals = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('./components/ActiveGoals.vue')
)
const ManageGoals = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
  import('./components/ManageGoals.vue')
)

const selectedTab = ref(ActiveGoals);
const setSelectedComponent = (tab) => {
  selectedTab.value = tab;
};

defineExpose({
  selectedTab,
  setSelectedComponent,
});

defineComponent({
  components: {
    TheHeader,
  },
});
</script>
```