# create an instance of vue 3 component with composition api

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Lets say I created a component with the following syntax in vue3

```
// Message.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
const props = defineProps<{
    message: string
}>();
</script>

<template>
<span>{{ props.message }}</span>
</template>
```

how can i create an instance of this Message component?

```
import Message from "./Message"

let message1 = Message({message:"hello world"}); // how to do this?
```

so i can use the *message1* with `<component>` like `<component :is="message1" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following import to the file.

```
import { createApp, h } from "vue";
```

and then create the message component in this way.

```
let message1 = createApp({ 
  setup () {
    return () => h(Message, {message: "hello world"});
  }
});
```

Comment: In this case message1 is an app, it's not supposed to be used as `<component :is="message1" />` like the OP requested

Answer (score 0):

Vue components aren't supposed to be instantiated only by the renderer, "instance" isn't the correct term here. The description suggests that it's wrapper component that is needed, it's sole purpose is to pass props to a child.

```
// HelloWorldMessage.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import Message from "./Message"
</script>

<template>
  <Message message="hello world"/>
</template>
```

It's still a good idea to explicitly define props if a wrapper is supposed to pass through some props, especially because TypeScript is in use. Functional components can be used for more flexibility, like explained in [this article](https://logaretm.com/blog/generic-type-components-with-composition-api/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
import Message from './Message'
```

won't work.

You have to explicitly specify `from './Message.vue'` to let the loader know the import is a `.vue` SFC.

---

Secondly, you cannot create a Vue component instance by calling its definition as a function.

In short:

```js
let message1 = Message({message:"hello world"});
console.log(message1)
```

never reaches `console.log` because it fails on first line with a `__Message__.default is not a function` error.

---

But, most importantly, the built-in [`is` special attribute](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#is) does not expect a component instance.

It expects either:

- a `string` matching the `name` of a registered component (definition)
- a component definition (the imported `Message`, in your case)

I am guessing `Message` is not a registered component from the fact you're importing it.
Which means the simplest solution would be to pass the component definition *itself* to `is` (using `:is="Message"`):

```html
<template>
  <component :is="Message" />
</template>
<script setup>
import Message from "./Message.vue"
</script>
```

---

In order to use the string name (e.g: `<component is="message" />`), you have to first register the `Message` component, using any of:

1. component declaration in current component:

```html
<template>
  <component is="message" />
</template>
<script>
import Message from './Message.vue'

export default {
  components: { Message }
}
</script>
```

2. component registration on app instance:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Message from './path/to/Message.vue'

const app = createApp()
app.component('message', Message)
app.mount('#app')

// now you can use `<component is="message" />` anywhere in the app
```

---

Side note: this won't work:

```html
<template>
  <component is="message" />
</template>
<script setup>
import Message from './Message.vue'
</script>
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75857132/1891677) why.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you have made a Vue application with a component called `App.vue`.

In `App.vue`, we can add our `Message` component using the following:

```html
<template>
    <Message message="Hello, world!" />
</template>

<script setup>
    import Message from './components/Message.vue';
</script>
```

In the `script` section of our `App.vue` file, we imported the component that we would like to add, in our case, `Message`. In the `template`, we passed our props as normal HTML variables.

---

Slightly longer example (for those who are interested).

We want to create a navigation bar with a title and three buttons. In our `App` component we can write:

```html
<!-- App.vue -->

<template>
    <NavigationBar />
    
    <!-- Other page content -->
</template>

<script setup>
    // Import our navigation bar
    import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar.vue';
</script>
```

We can implement our navigation bar using:

```html
<!-- components/NavigationBar.vue -->

<template>
    <nav id="navbar">
        <AppTitle>App Title</AppTitle>
        
        <div id="button-list">
            <AppButton id="testimonial-button">Testimonials</AppButton>
            <AppButton id="contact-button">Contact</AppButton>
            <AppButton id="about-button">About</AppButton>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script setup>
    // Import components
    import AppTitle from './AppTitle.vue';
    import AppButton from './AppButton.vue';
</script>

<style scoped>
    /* Add styling */
    
    #navbar, #button-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
</style>
```

Then we can implement the two components that make our navigation bar.

```html
<!-- components/AppTitle.vue -->

<template>
    <h1 class="title">
        <slot />
    </h1>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>

<style scoped>
    /* Add styling */
    
    h1 {
        font-family: Rubik, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!-- components/AppButton.vue -->

<template>
    <button class="app-button" type="button">
        <slot />
    </button>
</template>

<script setup>
</script>

<style scoped>
    /* Add styling */
    
    .app-button {
        padding: 2%;
    }
</style>
```